# list top 10 files by size in a unix directory

Tags: c++, file, list

I am trying a to read a unix directory (including all subdirectories) using c++ and list the top 10 largest files.
I have read that I can use #include dirent.h and use struct dirent but I am having trouble passing the directory name as a variable to opendir/readdir.
Basically it doesn't recognise it and says file/directory not found.
Please can you help me with how I can do this in c++ and print out the top 10 largest files in the directory? Thanks

```
DIR *dir;
struct dirent *ent;
dir = opendir ("homedir");
if (dir != NULL) {
    while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
        cout << ent->d_name <<endl;
    }

    closedir (dir);
} else {
    cout << "Can't open directory" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Post some code, then you might have a chance of getting some help.

Comment: DIR *dir;
struct dirent *ent;
 dir = opendir ("homedir");
if (dir != NULL) {
while ((ent = readdir (dir)) != NULL) {
   cout << ent->d_name <<endl;
}
closedir (dir);
} else {
   cout << "Can't open directory" << endl;
}

Comment: Thanks. Homedir is name of a variable to my home directory but I can't seem to get the above to evaluate this correctly. It keeps saying file/directory not found

Comment: I am also not too sure how to list the files by size and then print out the top ten largest files

Comment: I've put the code in your question. You can add to and modify the question yourself with the small edit link below your question.

Comment: If "homedir is a name of a variable" then maybe you should get it's value! `char* homedir = getenv ("homedir"); dir = opendir (homedir);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't really give enough details, but when you are reading
recursively, are you postfixing the names you read to the
previous names.  Reading a directory doesn't change the current
directory, so your function should look more or less like:

```
std::vector
readDirectoriesRecursively( std::string const& path )
{
    std::vector results;
    for each name in path
        if is directory
            results.insert(
                results.end(),
                readDirectoriesRecursively( path + '/' + filename ) ) ;
        else
            results.push_back( FileInfo( path + '/' + filename ) );
    return results;
}
```

In the constructor of `FileInfo`, use `stat` to obtain the size.  Once you have the results, sort by size, and output the first 10.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You have all the filenames. With these, you can do a [`stat`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/stat) to obtain the filesize for each file. When you sort the filesizes descending, you have the ten largest files.

```
struct stat buf;
stat(ent->d_name, &buf);
```

See the detailed example in the man page.

Comment: Ok thanks alot. I am stuck trying to pass the variable homedir as it says this doesn't exist. If I hardcode this as /home/james this works but if I pass the above loop the variable homedir it doesn't recognise it. I have tried this with double quotes/single quotes and without them

Comment: @user1914520 Your "homedir" is just a string, what do you mean with variable? If you want to access an environment variable, use [`getenv()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getenv). In this case it would be `getenv("HOME")`.